# Proving,that if $a$ and $a \implies b$ are tautologies,then $b$ is a tautology.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

How do I prove this?I know,that tautology is a statement that always is true.I'm pretty new to this type of logic and I got stuck.

Comment: Modus ponens? What tools are available to you?

Comment: Modus ponens is discussed later in the book so I'm bit hesitant to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can even prove by contradiction, if $b$ is not a tautology, then there must be a substitution such that $b$ is false, but then $a \implies b$ would not be a tautology because $(\top \implies \bot) \equiv \bot$ thus $b$ must be a tautology.

Comment: It's perfectly clear now,thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that $(a\implies b) \iff ((\neg a) \vee b)$

Comment: Maybe it would be nice to have a bracket around $a \Rightarrow b$ to make things clearer (the OP seems to be new to these things).

Comment: Updated, thanks!